# flask just refresh templated portion of page

Tags: javascript, html, flask

I have a simple flask app that uses templates.

Every time I click somewhere on the navigation (in the base.html) it refreshes the entire page, I'd rather it just refresh inside the template because I have collapsable elements in the navbar that go back to being collapsed when the entire page is reloaded.

How do I just reload the new template I want to render and not the nav bar when I click on a link in the nav bar?

for reference here's some code:

base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    ...
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      // Hide submenus
      $('#body-row .collapse').collapse('hide');

      // Collapse/Expand icon
      $('#collapse-icon').addClass('fa-angle-double-left');

      // Collapse click
      $('[data-toggle=sidebar-colapse]').click(function() {
          SidebarCollapse();
      });

      function SidebarCollapse () {
          $('.menu-collapsed').toggleClass('d-none');
          $('.sidebar-submenu').toggleClass('d-none');
          $('.submenu-icon').toggleClass('d-none');
          $('#sidebar-container').toggleClass('sidebar-expanded sidebar-collapsed');

          // Treating d-flex/d-none on separators with title
          var SeparatorTitle = $('.sidebar-separator-title');
          if ( SeparatorTitle.hasClass('d-flex') ) {
              SeparatorTitle.removeClass('d-flex');
          } else {
              SeparatorTitle.addClass('d-flex');
          }

          // Collapse/Expand icon
          $('#collapse-icon').toggleClass('fa-angle-double-left fa-angle-double-right');
      }
    </script>
    <style>
    </style>

    {% include 'nav-mini.html' %}

    <!-- Bootstrap row -->
    <div class="row" id="body-row">

        {% include 'nav-side.html' %}

        <!-- MAIN -->
        <div class="col py-3">
          <article class=flashes>
            {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
              {% if messages %}
                <ul>
                  {% for message in messages %}
                    <li>{{ message}}</li>
                  {% endfor %}
                </ul>
              {% endif %}
            {% endwith %}
          </article>

          {% block content %}
          {% endblock %}
        </div>
        <!-- Main Col END -->

    </div>
    <!-- body-row END -->
  </body>
</html>
```

sidenav.html

```
<!-- Sidebar -->
<div id="sidebar-container" class="sidebar-expanded d-none d-md-block col-2">
    <ul class="list-group sticky-top sticky-offset">
      {% if sidenavs %}
        {% for heading, stuff in sidenavs.items() %}
          <li class="list-group-item sidebar-separator-title text-muted d-flex align-items-center menu-collapsed">
            <a href="#page{{heading}}" data-toggle="collapse" class="dropdown-toggle">
              <br />
              {{ heading }}
            </a>
          </li>
          <br />
          <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="page{{heading}}">
          {% for name, address in stuff.items() %}
            <a href="{{ address }}" class="bg-dark list-group-item list-group-item-action">
              <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-start align-items-center">
                <span class="fa fa-tasks fa-fw mr-3"></span>
                <span class="menu-collapsed">{{ name }}</span>
              </div>
            </a>
          {% endfor %}
          </ul>
        {% endfor %}
      {% endif %}
    </ul>
    <div class="footer">
      <h3><center>WCF Insurance</center></h3>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- sidebar-container END -->
```

[image: visual]

App.py (flask app)

```
...
from flask import Flask, url_for, render_template, redirect, jsonify
...
app = Flask(__name__)
CWD = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
...
@app.route('/bokeh-example')
def page_bokeh_example():
    ''' iframe for Bokeh Example '''
    resp = {
        'mininavs': get_mini_nav(),
        'sidenavs': get_side_nav(),
        'iframe_url': get_iframe_url('Bokeh Example'), }
    return render_template('iframe.html', **resp)
....
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5020)
```

Notice I'm using the `render_template()` flask function.

Comment: @GOATNine sorry no, I was loading a bokeh server, which was responsive, so I found that sufficient for my use case, if you find a solution using flask please point me to it. I'm sure there's a way.

Comment: I have a working answer, I'm just dealing with a small bug involving animations of the menu opening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a JavaScript function call to the onload property of the body tag with the following code in it

```js
function setMenuState(){
  if (window.sessionStorage.getItem("MenuState") == null){
    window.sessionStorage.setItem("MenuState", "--isHidden");
  }

  if(window.sessionStorage.getItem("MenuState") != "--isHidden"){
    toggleMenu();
    window.sessionStorage.setItem("MenuState", "");
  }
}

function toggleMenu(){
  const textnames = ["","",""]
  const sidebarE1 = document.getElementsByClassName("sidebar")[0];
  const contentE1 = document.getElementsByClassName("content")[0];
  let menuItems = document.getElementsByClassName("fa");
  sidebarE1.classList.toggle("sidebar--isHidden");
  contentE1.classList.toggle("content--isHidden");
  for(item in menuItems){
    if(menuItems[item].innerHTML === textnames[item]){
      menuItems[item].innerHTML = "";
    }else{
      menuItems[item].innerHTML = textnames[item];
    }
  }
  if(window.sessionStorage.getItem("MenuState") != "--isHidden"){
    window.sessionStorage.setItem("MenuState", "--isHidden");
  }else{
    window.sessionStorage.setItem("MenuState", "");
  }
}
```

```html
<body onload="setMenuState()">
```

This still runs the animation of the menu if it's open when you click on a link, but it retains the open/closed state in session storage.

UPDATE:
I have solved(mostly) the animations issue where the menu animation would play on page load.

```js
function setMenuState(){
  const sidebarE1 = document.getElementsByClassName("sidebar")[0];
  const contentE1 = document.getElementsByClassName("content")[0];
  if (window.sessionStorage.getItem("MenuState") == null){
    window.sessionStorage.setItem("MenuState", "--isHidden");
  }

  if(window.sessionStorage.getItem("MenuState") != "--isHidden"){
    toggleMenu();
    window.sessionStorage.setItem("MenuState", "");
  }
  setTimeout(()=>{
  if(!sidebarE1.classList.contains("sidebar-animated")){
    sidebarE1.classList.add("sidebar-animated");
    contentE1.classList.add("content-animated");
  }}, 250);
}
```

```css
.content {
  background-color: #000000;
  padding: 2rem;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
  margin-left: 4rem;
  color: #00ff00;
  top: 8rem;
  overflow: scroll;
  padding-bottom: 32rem;
  z-index: 1;
}
.content-animated {
  transition: transform 500ms linear;
}
```

by moving the actual transition property into its own css class, and only adding the class ~250ms after page load, the position and state of the menu is set without animation, and the animation is set before first click.